# Linux WaitForSingleObject?

Tags: c++, linux, wait

Here a piece of code showing the problem

//main

```
Process* process = NULL;
while(!process) {
    cout<<endl<<"Waiting for second process.\nPress any key";
    getchar();
    getchar();

    process = Process::takeExisting("process");
}
Process::waitEnd(process); //Problem here
cout<<endl<<"second process ended";
```

//Process::waitEnd

```
static void waitEnd(Process* proc) {
        int w = waitpid(proc->hProcess, &(proc->exitCode), WCONTINUED);
        Debug::error(errno," waitpid error - ");
    }
```

I've tried: stop first, wait second ends, continue first.

The problem: the second process is not child( I run it from second console ) so with this code errno is equal to 10. 
How to solve this on Linux?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DietrichEpp run first process, wait while second not open, open another console, run second process, wait while it ends, continue first

Comment: What do you mean by "wait while second not open"?  What are you waiting for?

Comment: What does `Process::takeExisting()` do, and how does it do it?  You may need to look at Linux's [`clone()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone).  However, in general, a process cannot inherit processes it did not spawn — the exception being the system process that inherits orphaned child processes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Process is my wrapper-class for processes. Process::takeExisting() - wraps real process with my class.

Comment: You cannot `wait()` or `waitpid()` for a process that you did not create.  How is the process created?

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yes I know, I run it in the second console, how to wait for such process?

Comment: Did you write both applications? Or are you in control of both of them? Why not making the second one connect to a socket / send a signal / use any other IPC to talk back to the first one?

Comment: Btw, the typical workarounds for waiting for a non-child process to finish (which you can't normally do) are `ptrace`ing it and waiting for an `exit_group` syscall, or polling by sending via `kill` the signal 0 to the other process and checking for `ESCHD`.

Comment: @peppe Just because I have the same Process::waitEnd() on windows and it works fine with WaitForSingleObject. I need to write the similar interface on linux. I hope that it possible to wait for other process, that not created by the first)

Comment: @peppe thanks I will try this

Comment: Using `kill` on a non-child process is unreliable. You can't make it race-free.